# Доработка скрипта кликера при достижении определенного значения

Tags: javascript

Есть страница, с примерно таким кодом:

```html
<tbody id="birr">
<tr class="tr_birr">
<td>...</td>
<tr class="tr_birr">
<td>...</td>
<tr class="tr_birr">
<td>...</td>
<tr class="tr_birr" height="30">
<td>...</td>
<td>...</td>
<td>...</td>
<td align="right">
<b>600 руб.</b>
</td>
</tbody>
```

Задача, получить сумму между тегами "b сумма /b", и при условии превышения этой суммы, например 700, делать клик.

Есть вот такой код:

```js
const el = document.getElementsByTagName('b');

let waiting = setInterval(() => {
  const bir = +el.innerText;
 if (bir >= 700) {
      document.getElementsByClassName('it')[1].click();
      //clearInterval(waiting);
     }
    else if(bir < 700) {
     //clearInterval(waiting);
    document.getElementsByClassName('it')[0].click();
 }
}, 2000);
```

Он не работает, видимо не видит сумму, потому что если получать значение по id все норм, но нужно брать значение именно между тегами b. Попытки получить сначала id и потом тег этого id тоже не увенчались, успехом, хотя все опробованные команды возвращают нужное значения между тегами b, помогите разобраться)
P.S. Количество tr и td постоянно меняется...

Comment: Есть догадка что innerText вытаскивает всю строку с "руб", и буквы мешают просчету, как можно вытащить только цифры, без букв и точки?

Comment: `console.log(el.innerText);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const bir = parseFloat(document.querySelector('td b').textContent);
```

---

```js
let str = '600 руб.';
let num = parseFloat(str);
console.log(str, '->', num);
```

Comment: С получением нужной инфы проблем нету, если подробнее, то на странице есть два места где выводятся итоговое число, оно одинаковое для каждого места, в одном месте его можно получить по id, в другом только по тегу b, ошибок при получении нету, разница лишь в том что по id возврат идет только цифрами 700 и все (так состряпана страница), а вот по тегу инпут выводит уже с буками 700 руб. и вот во втором случае когда есть буквы скрипт и не работает, поэтому вопрос в том как получить из тега b только цифры, без букв?

Comment: @Влад Я Вам написал, как получить "только цифры".

Comment: Все равно что-то не то, вот простой код: const el = parseFloat(document.getElementsByTagName('b')[1].textContent);

setInterval(() => {
 if (el >= 1000) {
      document.getElementsByClassName('it')[1].click();
     }
}, 2000);   не работает, хотя поиск возвращает цифры, и команда клик тоже рабочая....

Comment: @Влад Значение `el` надо вычислять внутри интервала.

Comment: Благодарю, разобрался, низкий вам поклон и дай бог здоровья и все такое....